# Not able to resolve Error in subplot function

Tags: matlab, subplot

This is my code:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = sin(x);
plot(x,y1)
title('Subplot 1: sin(x)')

subplot(2,2,2)
y2 = sin(2*x);
plot(x,y2)
title('Subplot 2: sin(2x)')

subplot(2,2,3)
y3 = sin(4*x);
plot(x,y3)
title('Subplot 3: sin(4x)')

subplot(2,2,4)
y4 = sin(8*x);
plot(x,y4)
title('Subplot 4: sin(8x)')
```

But I am getting this error:
Execution of script subplot as a function is not supported:
/MATLAB Drive/subplot.m

My file is named 'hello.m'

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: You probably have a file named `subplot.m` in your workspace, left from an earlier attempt - check it out and rename or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you are overriding the built-in `subplot` function with a script you created with the same name, `subplot.m`, and is present on the path.

I would suggest to run:

`which subplot`

in matlab command window, this will return the path to the file/function that matlab is using, most probably in your case the custom made one, not the built-in.

The built-in path should look more or less like this:

`...\MATLAB\R20xxy_x64\toolbox\matlab\graph2d\subplot.m` where 20xxy is your version (ie 2022a)

If you are overriding it will return the path to you script instead, `.. /MATLAB Drive/subplot.m`

The solution is to rename your script. I would strongly advice to avoid renaming or modifying the built-in function